# Persistent Header & Footer

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I have two divs with width 100%. I want one to always be on top of all content, and I want the second to be always on the bottom of everything. How can I do this? Preferably in pure CSS but I'll try jQuery/JS solutions if I need to.

I tried adding the header using include("header.php"); and header.php contains just the HTML code of the header. However, it doesn't work, but putting that exact code in place of the include works fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with position:fixed and defining either top and left properties or bottom and left properties.

Check out [CSS sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) while you're at it (deprecated link).

---

A new sticky positioning has been introduced in CSS. A stickily positioned element is treated as relatively positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed until it reaches the boundary of its parent. Using fixed and sticky positioning you can implement headers and footers that are always on top of everything else.

Sticky positioning might not be available to all browser versions that the end-user might use. For achieving sticky footers in older browsers do check [How to make a sticky footer using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069498/how-to-make-a-sticky-footer-using-css)

Comment: looks like www.cssstickyfooter.com is no longer up. Might want to do something about that link...

Comment: CSS support for sticky elements has improved in the last 6 years. CSS currently supports `position:sticky` out-of-the-box. The positioning is supported [by the latest browser versions](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky). To support older browser versions you might be adviced to check a later stackoverflow question on sticky footers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069498/how-to-make-a-sticky-footer-using-css. Thanks for taking the time to point out a deprecated answer!

Answer (score 3):

Use position:fixed and either top or bottom [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/wgWgd/).

```
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
#top {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;   
    background-color: black;

    top:0px;
    position: fixed;   
}

#bottom {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;   
    background-color: black; 

    bottom:0px;
    position: fixed;   
}

#content {
    padding-top: 10px;   
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="top">top header</div>

    <div id="content">content</div>

    <div id="bottom">bottom footer</div>
</body>
```

### - Keep in mind

...that flash applications will usually appear over elements like this. To get around this, use the `wmode="transparent"` attribute in objects/embedd. **Example:**

```
<object>
    <param name="movie" value="example.swf" /> 
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> 
    <embed src="example.swf" wmode="transparent"></embed>
</object>
```