# How to make a sticky footer using CSS?

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I want to keep my footer at the bottom of the page. I try this

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
```

but my footer getting messy. My website is made in WordPress. If possible I don't want to use any plugin for this. And I want to use a pure CSS only.

Here the CSS script

```
footer #bottom-footer{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
border-top: 5px solid #F80000;
text-align: left;
padding: 9px;
font-size: 13px;
}
.footer-wrap a{
color:#000000;
}
.footer-wrap a:hover{
color:#F80000;
}
.footer-logo a {
margin-bottom: 6px;
display: block;
}
.footer-socials {
float: left;
line-height: 0px;
}
.footer-socials a {
border-radius: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
margin-left: 3px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 30px;
}
.footer-socials a.facebook {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1f69b3;
}
.footer-socials a.twitter {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #43b3e5;
}
.footer-socials a.gplus {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #d84734;
}
.footer-socials a.youtube {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #df2126;
}
.ak-contact-address .socials a.pinterest {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ff3635;
}
.footer-socials a.linkedin {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1a7696;
}
.footer-socials .socials a.flickr {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e1e2dd;
}
.footer-socials .socials a.vimeo {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #7fdde8;
}
.footer-socials .socials a.instagram {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #c8c5b3;
}
.footer-socials .socials a.tumblr {
background: #395976;
}
.footer-socials .socials a.rss {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fbc95d;
}
.footer-socials .socials a.github {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #383838;
}
.footer-socials .socials a.stumbleupon {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e94c29;
}
.footer-socials .socials a.skype {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #09c6ff;
}
.footer-socials .social-icons span {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
}
.footer-socials .socials i {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.tagcloud a{
font-size: 13px !important;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
padding: 8px 10px;
margin: 0 2px 4px 0;
display: inline-block; 
line-height: 1;
}
.sidebar .tagcloud a{
background: #23A38F;
color: #FFF;
}
```

[Website link](https://www.homecredit.ph/betasite)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Following a clean method implemented from an online source no longer available (dead link), the minimum code you should need for your page would be (note - probably best to use `#bottom-footer` instead of `footer #bottom-footer` for the selection of your footer - that could be part of the issue):

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
#bottom-footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 7):

This works perfect. It's the example from W3SCHOOLS

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_footer.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The link is dead, `404`

Comment: Updated link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_footer.asp

Answer (score 6):

A couple modern methods using a sprinkle of [flex box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) CSS and the following HTML structure:

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

**Method 1**: (fixed height footer) Apply `display:flex` and `flex-direction:column` to the `body`.  Apply `flex:1` (`flex-grow:1`) to the `main` element.

The main element will grow vertically to occupy any empty space, thus making the footer stick to the bottom.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
}

header {
  background-color: #cffac7;
  height:50px;
}

main {
  background-color: #f8e2ff;
  flex:1;
}

footer {
  background-color: #fceec7;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

**Method 2**: (fixed height footer) Apply `display:flex` and `flex-direction:column` to the `body`. Apply `margin-top:auto` the `footer`.

You're done, because [auto margins inside flex containers absorb all available free space](https://hackernoon.com/flexbox-s-best-kept-secret-bd3d892826b6), making the footer stick to the bottom. Note that this is not dependent on main having any height or content. In this case, we've given main no flex rules at all, and so it gets the default value of `flex:initial` (`flex: 0 1 auto`).

```css
body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-height: 100vh;
      margin:0;
    }

    header {
      background-color: #cffac7;
      height:50px;
    }

    main {
      background-color: #f8e2ff;
    }

    footer {
      background-color: #fceec7;
      height:50px;
      margin-top:auto;
    }
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

**Method 3**: (fluid height footer) This is really the same technique as in #1 but with elements that have no intrinsic height. By virtue of the ratio between the (unitless) `flex-grow` values given to the competing elements, `main` will grow at five times the rate as the `header` and `footer`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
}

header {
  background-color: #cffac7;
  flex:1;
}

main {
  background-color: #f8e2ff;
  flex:5;
}

footer {
  background-color: #fceec7;
  flex:1 
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has a sticky footer you can use.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Or you can just do it with CSS and jQuery:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I try the sticky footer from css-tricks, but the footer still not sticky

Answer (score 2):

## Working 2019 Solution with CSS Grid

If you're here, then you probably suffered for far too long like I did :)

Here's a solution that *will* work. It's what I use for my site here:

https://aleksandrhovhannisyan.github.io/

You can verify that it works regardless of how much content is on a page by navigating to a fake URL under my site domain:

[image]

I'll keep things very generic and reusable. Below is all the code you need, with a basic DOM consisting of a fixed top navigation/navbar, a main content area, and a sticky footer.

I recommend you run and view it in full-page mode to verify that it works:

[image]

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    /* Replace 80 with your footer height, or with auto for variable-height footers */
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 80px;
    /* These two are important */
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

#topnav {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  /* Recommended by Google, but adjust as you see fit */
  min-height: 64px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* This is to ensure that it always appears above everything. */
  z-index: 100;
  left: 0;
}

#page-content {
    grid-row: 1;
    /* https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/ */
    min-width: 0;
    /* change as you see fit */
    padding-bottom: 64px;
    padding-top: 64px;
}

#page-footer {
    background: black;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    grid-row: 2;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="topnav">topnav stuff goes in here</nav>
    </header>
    <main id="page-content">
        <h1>Page content goes here</h1>
    </main>
    <footer id="page-footer" class="container">
        <div>Made by Name</div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here

[Modern Clean CSS “Sticky Footer”](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/)

```
html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}
body {
margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
}
```