# Is there a simple html code to stick a footer at the bottom on a page with minimal content? (without using CSS)

Tags: html, footer

I was hoping to find some way of entering code in the footer tag (like in my example) to stick the footer at the bottom instead of just below the end of my content. Is there a way to do this without CSS? Sorry if my terminology is off, I just started learning html a few days ago.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head><title> Sample Website </title></head>
<body>I want the footer at the bottom of the page</body>

  <footer height="0">This is a footer test for a short page</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not use css? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: That's the point of CSS. It's akin to wanting your house to be blue without using paint.

Comment: ^^ To that point OR wanting your carpet stuck to the floor without using staples ..

Comment: I'm ok with using CSS if that's the only way to do it. I was just curious if there's an html code for it. I don't want to feel overwhelmed in learning more than html at the moment.

Comment: You *must* learn more than just HTML as HTML is just markup language that does nothing on it's own (similar to XML)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a sticky footer using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069498/how-to-make-a-sticky-footer-using-css)

Comment: It's pretty simple.   `<footer style="height: 100px; width: 100%; position: fixed; bottom:0; left:0;">This is a footer test for a short page</footer>`

Comment: That's fair but no there isn't a way.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do it with HTML alone, short of glomming in a bunch of empty lines, which would be specific to only one screen size.  There is probably a way to do it with JavaScript that would be bad.  The proper way to do it would be with CSS.  BUT-- you could just not have it stuck to the bottom of the page for now while you're still learning just HTML.  Also, a sticky footer is a problem that is somewhat notoriously more difficult than it looks-- so I would suggest if you're just learning leave that particular task for a later time.

Comment: Thank you @Zak that worked. Thanks everyone for the input, I wasn't aware how necessary CSS is.

Comment: When learning HTML, the very first thing you need to understand is the *purpose* of HTML, which is **describing the semantic structure of your document**. It is in no way part of HTML's job to influence *how* things are displayed - that is the sole responsibility of CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this with VERY minimal CSS..

```css
footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  This is a footer test for a short page
</footer>
```

OR you can use inline CSS:

```
<footer style="height: 100px; width: 100%; position: fixed; bottom:0; left:0;">This is a footer test for a short page</footer>
```

Comment: It's not as easy as this.

Comment: The positions you are using are applied relative to the `body` element, which, if not covering the whole screen, will make the footer sit somewhere right in the middle of the screen. So while your CSS shows part of what is needed, it doesn't address or even mention this basic issue.

Comment: I'm just using the Notepad program and saving as an html file. The inline CSS code worked. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I'm wondering if this could be as simple as adding the following code to the bottom of your `HTML` document.

```
<footer>
  <p>Williz</p>
</footer>
```

[This w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp) provides some more context if you are interested. Overall, I agree 100% with Zak's comments and suggestions.

Comment: No, it's not as simple. The `footer` element doesn't mean anything in terms of positioning. It's used for semantic reasons.